# Sci-Fi movie with attacking trees and vines (Asian) - YouTube scene

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, horror

I recently found a small scene on YouTube in which a group of soldiers is attacked by plants/vines/tentacles. Looks like an interesting fantasy/sci-fi horror movie.

Here is the scene:

Does anybody know the title of that movie?

Comment: In case this helps, both the subtitles and the audio are Chinese.

Comment: The same YouTube user has uploaded several clips, apparently all from the same movie, featuring the guy with black leather clothes and sunglasses. Based on the synopsis, it *might* be ["Iron Blood Guard"](https://moviesandmania.com/2021/02/05/iron-blood-guard-movie-film-sci-fi-action-chinese-2021-overview/), however said guy with sunglasses doesn't appear in that movie's trailer, and I can't say any of the listed actors look similar to the people in those YouTube clips.

Comment: I've already seen the "Tron Blood Guard" trailer but i think that the scenes are similar but not the same... I can't find the main actor with the glasses or other actors ... I think its not the right movie... If we can identify the name of one actor i could be possible to look at databases like IMDB

Comment: Unfortunately, it also looks like none of the scenes posted to YouTube has dialogue that mentions the full name of any character, other than one of the women's (?) surnames, 顾 (Gu). That is not much to go by.

Comment: Too bad... I*ve also tried the reverse google picture search (screenshot upload) but that failed too...

Comment: Haha, me too. That is, I picked some stills of which I could imagine that they are "impressive" enough to appear in other material, but to no avail.

Comment: That algorithm is very good, in a normal case it can detect similar pictures very well (from Trailers or review pages, etc. )  but this time it failed.... Someone asked about the movie title also on the youtube comment page i hope that the Uploader is responding

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is *Chong Qi Zhi She Gu Fo Tui* (重启之蛇骨佛蜕) or ***[Reunion: Escape from the Monstrous Snake](https://grave-robbers-chronicles.fandom.com/wiki/Reunion:_Escape_from_the_Monstrous_Snake)*** (2021).

From the Grave Robbers Chronicles Wiki:

> In order to rescue his former comrades, Hei Yan Jing goes deep into Cambodia's dense forests and fights against strange insects and hidden things in an underground palace to solve the mystery of his missing comrades.

[image]

Comment: How did you find it? And what's the plot?

Comment: The scene in question is round about [55:23](https://youtu.be/cXBJ9wObN0E?t=3323)

Comment: @FuzzyBoots jumping randomly on youtube and finally found https://www.youtube.com/c/HKCinema/videos

Comment: OH WOW YES THAT IS IT :D MANY MANY THANKS :D :D What a great movie, hope they will release an english version too :D :D

Answer (score -1):

This film is part of "The Lost Tomb" or "The Grave Robber Chronicles" (DaoMu Biji), a chinese TV franchise series with 8 parts and 5 films to the moment. Is a tomb raiders adventure series based in the books written by Xu Lei.
The guy in black glasses is Hai Yan Ning or Xie Xiazi (Black Blindman), interpreted by Ji Chen, the same actor and character in Tomb of the Sea (Sha Hai, 2018 TV Series).
Xie Xiazi is a blind guy, but he have the hability of see clearly only in the dark, then, always had sunglasses.

Comment: This should perhaps be a comment rather than an answer