# Asian film with plants attacking 3 girls

Tags: story-identification, movie, plants

I happened to find a link to a channel on YouTube in regards to a YouTube video called "Vines Plant Attack 3 Girls." The video has been taken down and there's only seems to be a screenshot of the YouTube video itself regarding the scene. Here's the image from the video.

[image: screenshot showing an asian woman with plant vines gripping her arms and body]

Link (taken down): [www.youtube.com/watch?v=wHuwHqcwG6k](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wHuwHqcwG6k)

If any other info is needed or has to be changed, let me know. Thank you.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/245254/sci-fi-movie-with-attacking-trees-and-vines-asian-youtube-scene

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AEwquP5BidA?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Bq_MnNYVRY ?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vuh9X5y76dc ?

Comment: Thank you Valorum, I was actually in search for the second one as well.

Comment: Was it our days or some medieval ?

Comment: I don't know unfortunately. That was all I got from that and the video was copyright claimed before I could find out.

Comment: Seems to be our time. Here is a sample from [another?] movie: https://youtu.be/ULv0MppLxYQ?t=64

Comment: Could be also Lost Tomb (1,2) https://m.imdb.com/title/tt10433136/?ref_=m_ttmi_tt , https://m.imdb.com/title/tt10433136/mediaviewer/rm3453655041/ (see https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/245254/sci-fi-movie-with-attacking-trees-and-vines-asian-youtube-scene, answer from @ErdReinhardt)

Comment: Looks like it's back up again. FWIW, the text, "怪藤捆绑缠住3位美女", is in Chinese.

Answer (score 6):

This clip is from the 2020 Chinese film **征途**, starting at 1h01m15s. The English title of this movie is **Double World**.

Here is the introduction of the plot from the movie's [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_World):

> In the fictional Central Plains continent, the kingdoms of Southern
> Zhao and Northern Yan have been locked in a fierce conflict. An
> assassination attempt on the King of Southern Zhao reignites the war.
> However, Southern Zhao is lacking a Field Marshal. At Grand Tutor
> Guan's suggestion, a tournament is held to find a new one, with each
> of the eight clans of Southern Zhao sending three warriors to compete.

The scene in question takes place during the second challenge of the tournament, which is to steal an egg from the lair of the Beast King.

[image]

Currently (January 2023) it is available to watch on Netflix and on YouTube.

Comment: Given that the YT video has been up for over two years without any concern from the rights holder, I'd guess it's safe to post

Comment: @Valorum, thank you for the edits!  I am maybe over-cautious about linking "unofficial" sources.